# mvn clean install fails

Tags: java, maven

I want to create a .jar file from my Java project and used `mvn clean install`.
However, it fails and troubleshooting the errors doesn't lead to success.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 965, Failures: 10, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  42.266 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-13T08:42:44+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2:test (default-test) on project *: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\<user>\Documents\GitHub\<github project>\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have used the -X switch and the -e switch and looked at http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException, but it doesn't give me any new insights into how to solve the problem.

I use Apache Maven 3.9.4 and Java version: 20.0.2.

Could any help me to solve this issue?

I tried running `mvn clean install` and I expected it to compile the project into a .jar file.

Comment: `Tests run: 965, Failures: 10` A jar can be built only after successful build

Comment: The issue isn't with maven. As the error says "There are test failures". Help us help you by sharing the failing test.

Answer (score 0):

Your build is having Test Failures.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2:test (default-test) on project *: There are test failures.
```

If you want to build your project by skipping Tests runs (not recommended)
you can use below configurations.

1. Add/Update Below plugin confirmation to your pom.xml

> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>   <configuration>
>     <skipTests>true</skipTests>
>   </configuration>
> </plugin>
> ```

2. While running maven clean install add skiptests as true.

> mvn clean install -DskipTests

Comment: First in general it is bad idea idea to skip tests. Apart from that if you configure that in your pom via the plugin configuration it will always skip the tests...

Comment: hi @khmarbaise
I have added not recommended in my answer